# What do these warning/restriction codes in air tickets mean?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, united-airlines

I bought airline tickets for a trip and received an email with these codes:

> `NONREF/0VALUAFTDPT/CHGFEE`

What do they mean? I don't think they are specific to the airline's system (United), that is, I think they are general airline codes.

The answer could be enriched with other possible codes.

Comment: There is a wealth of information here - not explanatory per se, but notes on fare rules written for use (it seems) by somebody familiar with the "jargon" involved. A number of extra codes are mentioned. Gives insight into practices, traps, ... .[**Travelocity - FARE RULES**](http://travel.travelocity.com/flights/AirFareRules.do;jsessionid=B200D77DF3982894EA57ED3FEE7D0D74.p0748?fare_basis_cd=WKX5NCE&dep_arp_cd=NYC&arr_arp_cd=PAR&aln_cd=SN&dep_dt=08/01/2010)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are not standard codes actually, sometimes they are similar but not always.

- **`NONREF`**: Non-refundable.
- **`0VALUAFTDPT`**: 0 value after scheduled departure. If you want to make any change make it before the departure time or the ticket has no value at all.
- **`CHGFEE`**: There is a change fee in case you want to change times.

Comment: Where did you find these codes? The answer would be even better with a link to all the codes if you found them on some website...

Comment: @hippietrail: HaLaBi works in air travel, so I imagine that's where this knowledge comes from.

Comment: @hippietrail sorry I do not have a link.. I tried to find any but could not find. there are no standard codes and codes depend on the reservation system and there are many systems (sabre, amadeus, stars....etc).

Comment: @HaLaBi: Thank you for your knowledge, and for sharing it!

Answer (score 2):

This is more a "related information" post than an answer per se, but it seems potentially useful enough for those interested in digging to be worth posting as an answer:

There is a wealth of information here - [**Travelocity - FARE RULES**](http://travel.travelocity.com/flights/AirFareRules.do;jsessionid=B200D77DF3982894EA57ED3FEE7D0D74.p0748?fare_basis_cd=WKX5NCE&dep_arp_cd=NYC&arr_arp_cd=PAR&aln_cd=SN&dep_dt=08/01/2010) - not explanatory per se, but notes on fare rules written for use (it seems) by somebody familiar with the "jargon" involved. A number of extra codes are mentioned. Gives insight into practices, traps, ... .

This is specific to one route - see below. But other material may be turned up by searching, based on the page's content. They say:

- RULE APPLICATION AND OTHER CONDITIONS
  NOTE - THE FOLLOWING TEXT IS INFORMATIONAL AND NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING. TRANSATLANTIC ROUNDTRIP STRUCTURE FARES FROM AREA 1 TO AREA 2/3. APPLICATION AREA THESE FARES APPLY FROM AREA 1 TO AREA 2/AREA 3. CLASS OF SERVICE THESE FARES APPLY FOR ECONOMY CLASS SERVICE. CAPACITY LIMITATIONS THE CARRIER SHALL LIMIT THE NUMBER OF PASSENGERS CARRIED ON ANY ONE FLIGHT AT FARES GOVERNED BY THIS RULE AND SUCH FARES WILL NOT NECESSARILY BE AVAILABLE ON ALL FLIGHTS. THE NUMBER OF SEATS, WHICH THE CARRIER SHALL MAKE AVAILABLE ON A GIVEN FLIGHT, WILL BE DETERMINED BY THE CARRIER'S BEST JUDGEMENT. OTHER CONDITIONS MILEAGE UPGRADE PERMITTED FOR BOOKING CLASSES B/Y/D/C/J. FOR FURTHER BOOKING CLASSES AND CONDITIONS CONTACT CARRIER FOR DETAILS.